# The ELB could not be updated due to the following error: Primary taskset target group must be behind listener arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to learn about `ECS` and `Blue/Green` deployments with `CodePipeline`.

I have been following several tutorials but I'm stuck with this error:

> The ELB could not be updated due to the following error: Primary
> taskset target group must be behind listener
> arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:XXX:listener/app/ecs-t-XXX/XXX/XXX.

**This is what I have:**

I created `2 listeners`: one for PROD (8080) and the other for TEST (8088)

I created `2 Target Groups`: one for each listener.
When I go to my `Load Balancer` and check the Listeners I can see them there.

I have `2 services`.
The original (Service1) and the new one (Service2)

Both services have the same configuration (except for the target group under load balancer: Service1 has the target-1 and Service2 the target-2).

`Service2` has `CODE_DEPLOY` as `DeploymentController` and `REPLICA` as `SchedulingStrategy` (Service1 doesn't)

In `CodePipeline`, when I reach the `deploy` action, it fails with the previous message.

The Load Balancer configuration seems fine:

- Listener 8080 forwards to target1
- Listener 8088 forwards to target2

I checked my `CodeDeploy` application and `deployment group`.

Everything seems fine. Under Load Balancing, I have target-1 which points to the PROD listener, and target-2 which points to the TEST listener.

In relation to the environment, the ECS Service is the Service2 (aka, the new one).

Permissions are fine.

So, what am I not seeing?
I searched about this error but I could not find an answer that worked for me.
The closest one was about not attaching the target groups to the Load Balancer. But in my case, I have them attached to the Load Balancer and the listeners are attached to the respective target group.

I'd appreciate help. I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue:

> I created 2 Target Groups: one for each listener. When I go to my Load Balancer and check the Listeners I can see them there.

If you've already pointed both listeners to their corresponding target groups, this issue will occur. Try pointing both the listeners to the same target group under which application is currently running.

More troubleshooting steps here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-blue-green-deployment/

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I made the change. Both listeners 8088 and 8088 are pointing to the target group of the Service1, however, it still fails with the same message: The ELB could not be updated due to the following error: Primary taskset target group must be behind listener arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:XXX:listener/app/ecs-t-XXX/XXX/XXX.

Comment: What resources are you following? Are you trying to add CodeDeploy Blue/Green to a new service or an existing service?

Comment: Again, thanks for your concern.
In the deployment group of my CodeDeploy application, I have the NEW service in the env configuration.
And under load balancing, target-1 and the PROD listener and then target-2 and test listener.

Comment: @Peter Hello, Are you able to resolve the issue? I'm also facing the same problem, tried a few hours but no resolution.